# Twitter URL Tweet Count - Private API?

Tags: php, twitter

I am writing a script in PHP to get data from the twitter API, I want to be able to access the number of 'tweets' for a given URL, in the PHP Facebook API this is easily possible with a single 'FQL Query', however, within Twitter I can only find the following :

http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.bbc.co.uk

From a little bit of research it would seem this is a 'private' API and only available to the 'tweet button' and not custom scripts. Is there an alternative way of achieving this which is considered OK?

Comment: Does it count shortened links? like t.co, or bit.ly or any other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works and does what you want, doesn't it?

I think if twitter would does not like you to use it, it would stop you from doing so. But that is just my opinion ;)

Comment: It does indeed return the numbers I want, but its not a public API which means it could be changed/removed/blocked at anytime, which would break any code based on it.Twitter don't want you to use it unless you are providing a 'Tweet This' button on a website, and are not so happy about 'aggregating data' this way.

Comment: They can also change every other API they have. Also if they change it the 'Tweet This' buttons would not work any more. So this is not likely.

Answer (score 2):

Use of this method outside of the Tweet Button is forbidden and should not be relied upon.